# How to share GNU Screen sessions

Tags: centos, gnu-screen

I want  to share a screen session, but this is harder then it seems for me.  What I did was `yum install screen` then I made a session with root `screen -S test`. After that i made it multiuser <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> `:multiuser on`.
I started a new SSH connection logged in as Foo and did `screen -ls`. All I get is `there is no socket at /var/run/screen/S-foo/`.

I also export the `SCREENDIR` to `/var/run/screen/` so it is only one DIR where the sessions are saved in. But the system don't allow for other user to own it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your user doesn't actually own the session it won't show up when using `screen -ls`.

You need to use

```
:acladd <username>
```

and then to attach

```
screen -r root/test
```

[more info](http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser)